# How to read and display sample(10) records while streaming Dataframe?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

I'm streaming some data from a Kafka topic. I want to stream a sample(10 records) of this data since there is a lot of data present in the topic and place it into a DataFrame. I want to display the data  on the console but I am unable to see any output. Also, I want to cast data in value column to string, deserialize it with avro schema and then read in json format

```
val df = spark.readStream.format("kafka").option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "brokerhost:xxxx").option("subscribe", "topic2").option("startingOffsets", "earliest").load()

scala> df.printSchema
root
 |-- key: binary (nullable = true)
 |-- value: binary (nullable = true)
 |-- topic: string (nullable = true)
 |-- partition: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- offset: long (nullable = true)
 |-- timestamp: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |-- timestampType: integer (nullable = true)


df.writeStream.format("console").start().awaitTermination() <-- Displays no output
```

Expected: Display the data from kafka topic on console and cast value column to string, deserialize it with avro schema and then read in json format

Comment: Can you use `kafka-console-consumer` to check if the data is really in `topic2`? I see no issues with the code and it should just work.

Comment: It is able to read  using `bin/kafka-avro-console-consumer` . Command used to connect using kafka-avro-console-consumer is `bin/kafka-avro-console-consumer --bootstrap-server brokerhost:XXX --topic topic2  --consumer.config  client-ssl.properties --property schema.registry.url="http://cp-schema-registry-data.com" --from-beginning`  . Not sure why it is unable to stream using the readstream command .  Are there any prerequisites that need to be taken care of before running the  `spark.readStream` command?

Comment: Can you use `spark-shell` and simply copy and paste the code to see if it works? Is Kafka secured (noticed `--consumer.config client-ssl.properties`)? What's the Spark version?

Comment: The snippet pasted in the question part is from spark-shell only. Is Kafka secured  -> Yes.   What's the Spark version --> version 2.2.1-mapr

Comment: Do you see any authentication errors? I'd expect some. I'm guessing that the queue cannot access the topic and the broker. You should simply copy all the properties from `client-ssl.properties` to use in the code with `kafka.` prefix (like `kafka.bootstrap.servers`) so they're in use by the underlying Kafka consumer. HTH

Comment: I did that and now it's failing for JAAS config file. I have switched to Java and I am able to unload the data. Not sure why the spark stream didn't work for me. Thanks a lot for your inputs .Appreciate it.

Comment: Can you elaborate on _"it's failing for JAAS config file."_? Do you see any errors? What are they? Edit your question and add it in.